# AmCharts4: amCore.percent() not working as intended

Tags: amcharts4

I have the following graph:
[image]

"1" is a LineSeries, and "2" is a columnSeries. I set the width of the columnSeries like this:

```
  series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(90);
```

But as you can see, the columns are far away from 90% width.

Interestingly, without the LineSeries, it looks like this, which is what I want it to look like:
[image]

Furthermore, if I write a very high value (80 000) instead of 90, I get the desired columns:

[image]

I noticed that the dateAxis behaves differently(different time showing), but I cannot see where this is coming from.

Also, this high value for percentage is not a solution, because it has different widths on different graphs

Comment: Hard to say without seeing code. Please post a fiddle of your setup with sample data that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So after experimenting I found out that the only way to avoid something like this is to use an own dateaxis for columns.

If, for example, you want a line+column, you can add a dateAxis to the line, and a dateAxis to the column.
If you have multiple columns, you could either use one dateAxis for all of them, or give one to every single column. The latter will make the columns "stack", so they are on the exact same positions if one would use the same dates for both datasets.
Furthermore, doing so means that you have to disable labeling on all dateaxes except for one, otherwise the labels on the xAxis will stack.